# Property does not exist on type 'Object' error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this funuction

```
getAll<T>() {
   return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/products`);
}
```

I am calling it like this:

```
this.productService.getAll()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(products => {
        debugger
        let s = products;
        this.products = products.response;
    });
```

I am getting error like this

`Property 'response' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)`

Server response could be anything Of this format:

```
{"status":200,"error":null,"response":[]}
{"status":200,"error":null,"response":{}}
{"status":200,"error":null,"response":"any string"}
```

Answer (score 0):

When subscribing to `HttpClient`, response body is received directly (unless requested otherwise) as demonstrated below;

```
this.productService.getAll().subscribe(body => this.products = body);
```

In addition there's no reason for using `first` operator since all Observables returned by `HttpClient` complete upon first emission.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is due to the expected type of returnable object not being specified in the call to **http.get()**.

By default, the **http.get()** method returns plain JSON. Therefore, the direct reference to an internal property (example:  json_data.response) will cause the type error.

**How to solve the problem?**

The problem can be solved by assigning the return type to http.get(), using <>

**Working code snippet**

```
getAll: Observable<MyReturnType>() {
   return this.http.get<MyReturnType>(`${environment.apiUrl}/products`);
}    

this.productService.getAll()
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(products => {
        let s = products;
        this.products = s.response;
    });
```

**More information:**
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Answer (score 0):

try to debug this by doing:

```
this.productService.getAll()
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(products => {
    console.log(products);
    let s = products;
    this.products = products.response;
});
```

I think the problem might be your backend here

If that does not help, try to force a type for the response.
you can do something like this:

```
getAll() { return this.http.get<{status: number, error: any, response: any}>(${environment.apiUrl}/products); }
```

if all of this does not help, try fixing your backend to send you just one type (object)
you should never return an array to a http request.
See here: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/